# Animation lag on heavy rerender

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My simplified code goes something like this

```
const Component = () => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState()
    React.useEffect(() => {
        async function asyncEffect() {
             const dataFromDb = await getAlotOfDataFromBackend()
             setData(dataFromDb)
        }
        asyncEffect();
    })

    return data? <SvgLoadingAnimation/> : <Table data={data}/>
}
```

My problem is that the loading animation starts to lag badly the moment setData is being called.  How can I solve this?

Comment: I have an update, so that this question does not confuse people who look for similar issue.

It turns out that there is absolutely nothing wrong with that piece of code from React side. It's actually the backend call `getAlotOfDataFromBackend`, that is so heavy on communication - it lags up the frontend at the moment when the value is returned. Didn't figure out how to fix the communication yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should wait for response, instead of setting data before it returns

```
  const Component = () => {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(null)
    React.useEffect(() => {
      const getData = async () => {
        const dataFromDb = await getAlotOfDataFromBackend()
        setData(dataFromDb)
       }
      getData()
    },[setData])

    return !data ? <SvgLoadingAnimation/> : <Table data={data}/>
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was an error in that code piece. Sadly this is not a fix to the problem itself.